# Rails: Migrating to Auth0 while retaining postgres records and associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, ruby-on-rails-5, data-migration, auth0

My project currently uses `has_secure_password` to handle users (similar to this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/270-authentication-in-rails-3-1)). Everything works fine but looking down the road, I feel that a switch to Auth0 will provide benefits and would like to make the transition now before too many users sign up.

Users are saved to a User model with several associations (checkins/comments/etc.) How can I link an Auth0 user to a User record on my database. I figured I could either lookup by email (since they will be unique) or Auth0 User Id (and add a new column to the user table) once they login. It seems like I could simply use the Auth0 login callback to sign the user in (using my current sessions controller) but how can I create users on my database when they are created in OmniAuth. Is there a callback for that as well?

In a perfect world I would like to do something like:

1. User signs up using Auth0 lock. Creating a new account on the Auth0 database.
2. Callback triggers a new record to be made on my database that contains all the information from Auth0 and has columns for associations.
3. User logs in and their user_id (from my database) is stored in sessions.
4. Changes the user makes to personal information (name/email/etc.) is changed on both databases.

Is what I want possible? Or should I stick with my current authentication?

Comment: That should be doable, but a few questions for clarification. Your plan is to use [omniauth-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/omniauth-auth0) to integrate Auth0 into your rails app, is that it? Also, would you be allowing users to login through Auth0 available social providers or just with username/password credentials?

Comment: I plan on using omniauth-auth0 but was hoping to use social providers. The only information my application currently gets from users is email, first name, last name, and password (only email and password being required) So if they connect with social that doesn't provide name then they would be assigned a random name (how no names are currently dealt with)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no major difference between implementing Auth0 authorization and any other OAuth provider such as Facebook, Twitter, Github etc. The [Auth0 quickstart guide](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/rails) is just kind of strange since it does not show how you would link credentials to a user model in the application. Rather they just shove the whole shebang into the session.

The only real change you need to do to your user model here is add a `uid` column which is used to store the Auth0 `uid` for the user.

Basically the OAuth flow with OmniAuth works like this:

1. The user clicks a link that redirects the user to the providers OAuth portal. (Or in the case of Auth0 its a fancy JS Widget)
2. The provider redirects back to your application and it goes to either the `callback` or `failure` method on your callbacks controller.
3. At this point the user may be a new or returning user. So you try to find the user in your application based on the `uid` from the [auth hash](https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth/wiki/Auth-Hash-Schema) or create a new user from the auth hash.
4. You sign in and redirect the user.

---

```
class Auth0Controller < ActionController::Base
  # the signed up or logged in on auth0
  # GET "/auth/auth0/callback"
  def callback
    auth_hash = request.env['omniauth.auth']
    @user = User.find_or_intialize_by(uid: auth_hash[:uid]) 

    if @user.new_record?
      @user.name = auth_hash.name
      @user.email = auth_hash.email # etc
      @user.save!
    end

    reset_session
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    redirect_to root_path, success: "Hello #{@user.name}"
  end

  # the user declined to give your app permissions
  # GET "/auth/failure"
  def failure
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "Oh noes"
  end
end
```

See:

- https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/webapp/rails
- https://github.com/omniauth/omniauth
- https://auth0.com/docs/connections/database/migrating

Comment: From my understanding, `request.env['omniauth.auth']` comes in as a JWT, correct?

Comment: Yes and no - the actual response from auth0 contains a JWT. The strategy ( [omniauth-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/omniauth-auth0)) converts this into a normalized hash like object which is stored in `request.env['omniauth.auth']`.